# How to distinct on a table with a pair of opposite id values and get one id pair?

Tags: postgresql, compare, distinct

I want to eliminate from a table with two id columns (aID, bId) the opposite Id pairs.

For example the aId = 123abc and the bId = 345def. The opposite side is aId = 345def and bId = 123abc. Another bId = 678def is not the opposite side from aId ! That should be listed.

How to get only one of this pairs, which one is even.

```
CREATE TABLE distinct_pair_of_id (
    "aId" VARCHAR,
    "bId" VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO distinct_pair_of_id ("aId", "bId")
VALUES
    ('123abc', '345def'),
    ('345def', '123abc'),
    ('123abc', '678def'),
    ('678def', '123abc'),
    ('345def', '986def'),
    ('345def', '765def')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `LEAST`/`GREATEST` trick here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(aId, bId) AS aId,
                GREATEST(aId, bId) AS bId
FROM distinct_pair_of_id;
```

This would also return records having only one value but no pair.  If you instead want to return only records which do have a pair, we can aggregate:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(aId, bId) AS aId,
       GREATEST(aId, bId) AS bId
FROM distinct_pair_of_id
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```